# Best way to proceed for KIOSK MODE/ creating a kiosk for a public space

Tags: kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm looking for advice and input into how other people have created touch screen kiosks in public space. Any recommendations, war stories, advice.

I see there are multiple kiosk mode applications. I am hoping to find one that is well maintained and offers support (no issue with paying) that is going to work well with a very large touch screen (~ also any advice on which ones might be best - looking for 70" ~).

I'd appreciate any input as I gather intel on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is use any linux, simple windows manager and nw.js as main application.